# If statement with multiple null string comparisons, print error with the ones that fail

Tags: bash, if-statement

Let's say I have the following if statement that checks multiple variables

```
if [[ -z ${var1} || -z ${var2} || -z ${var3} ]]; then
   echo "Error, one or more variables are empty"
   exit 2
fi
```

I'm looking for a way in which I can do the same test, but somehow be able to print the exact variables that are empty, something like this:

```
if [[ -z ${var1} || -z ${var2} || -z ${var3} ]]; then
   echo "Error, the following variables are empty: ${var1} and ${var3}"
   exit 2
fi
```

Of course, I could test them individually:

```
if [[ -z ${var1} ]]; then
   echo "Error, the following variable is empty: ${var1}"
   exit 2
fi
if [[ -z ${var2} ]]; then
   echo "Error, the following variable is empty: ${var2}"
   exit 2
fi
if [[ -z ${var3} ]]; then
   echo "Error, the following variable is empty: ${var3}"
   exit 2
fi
```

But this method also has a big flaw: if there are multiple empty variables, the script will exit after the first one, you'll never know that others are also empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility, using indirect expansion:

```
empty=()
for i in var1 var2 var3; do
    [[ -z ${!i} ]] && empty+=( "$i" )
done

if ((${#empty[@]})); then
    echo "Error, the following variables are empty: ${empty[*]}"
    exit 2
fi
```

The advantage of the loop that checks for variables is that you don't have to duplicate code.

Comment: This is, by far, the best approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of executing `exit 2` immediately, set a flag (say `error=1`) and then add the following after the third `if`:

```
[[ $error ]] && exit 2
```

You could also use a loop instead of manually repeating all these `if`s and `echo`s:

```
for varname in var1 var2 var3
do
    if [[ -z "${!varname}" ]]
    then
        echo "Error, the following variable is empty: $varname"
        error=1
    fi
done

[[ $error ]] && exit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine your code pieces like this:

```
if [[ -z ${var1} ]]; then
    echo "Error, the following variable is empty: ${var1}"
fi
if [[ -z ${var2} ]]; then
   echo "Error, the following variable is empty: ${var2}"
fi
if [[ -z ${var3} ]]; then
   echo "Error, the following variable is empty: ${var3}"
fi

if [[ -z ${var1} || -z ${var2} || -z ${var3} ]]; then
   exit 2
fi
```

Comment: I thought about this sort of mix, but in my situation, it wouldn't help. I need to be able to have a one sentence output that lists all empty variables.